# Set wallpaper in the Lock Screen

Tags: login-screen, customization, desktop-background, lock-screen

Is there an app or some way to set the desktop wallpaper as viewable when only logged in, and to set another when logged out or **locked**? I've tried Ubuntu Tweak, but it only does the login wallpaper, and doesn't do the lock screen wallpaper.

Comment: I think it's not possible to change wallpaper in lock screen view

Comment: Yours is a question I have been researching for many days. With the release of GNOME3, used in 12.04+, things have been made much harder to mess with the settings. If you're not running 12.04, try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250539/what-is-wrong-with-this-method-of-using-an-alternate-lock-screen-background). But, unfortunately, so far it is impossible.