# What is wrong with this method of using an alternate lock screen background?

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background, command-line, lock-screen

I have recently been trying to separate all three wallpaper states that are all the same as default. They are:

1. Unity Greeter
2. Lock screen
3. Desktop

All of them have a wallpaper, and as default the three are all the same and changed by changing the desktop wallpaper. It is fairly simple to [change the log in background in LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm), but I haven't found any successful attempts to change the lock screen background and 'free' it from the consistent background setting.

I was looking around for a solution, and I got this:

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename --type string /path/to/image.jpg
```

But it just doesn't work. No errors, no notes - it simply does affect the settings at all. The file it edits exists, and it looks reasonably legitimate for the purpose - but it's ineffective.

How would you correct the command or diagnose the problem with it?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal and am running Unity (if that isn't already obvious).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? gconftool became sort of obsolete so this will not work anymore.

Comment: 12.10, sorry. I'll add that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible in Gnome 2. In newer versions, the background picture in the lockscreen will always be the same as the background of the user currently logged in.